# Why is Django's __icontains and __iregex Behaving Weirdly in my Code?

Tags: python, mysql, regex, django

I have an `Articles` model where users save their articles that could have some words hashtagged in them.

Just like on Twitter, I want when users click on those hashtags, it should pull the all the articles that have the clicked hashtag in them but the code is behaving weirdly.

If I have three post that have `#itertools` in them, I expect the three of them when `#itertools` is clicked but I get only one of them and sometimes I get empty and sometimes I get all the articles. If I post another article with #fetchThis hashtag and I click on it, the search seem to find no match and return empty query even after refreshing the page.

I really cannot fathom why this is happening. Both `__iregex` and `__icontains` give the same result, weirdly.

Here is the code:

```
def hash_tags(request, hash_tag):
    tag = '#' + hash_tag    
    data = Articles.objects.filter(content__iregex=r"^[^.]*{0}*[[:>:]]".format(tag))

    #---> or __icontains. The space added to tag is intentional. 
    #---> To avoid fetching articles with itertoolsss in them.

    #tag += ' '
    #data = Articles.objects.filter(content__icontains=tag)

    if len(data):
        fetched_articles = len(data)
    else:
        data = ["No data matches your search!"]
        fetched_articles = 0

    context = {'articles': articles, 'fetched_articles':fetched_articles}
    return render(request, 'mysite/hashtags.html', context)
```

What am I doing wrong? I am stuck here for days now.

*I use Django 1.6 and MySQL*

Comment: who is ``articles`` which you are putting in the context?. Also why ``fetched_articles`` is the length instead of the articles? Also, why using ``if len(data)`` instead of ``if data.exists`` ?

Comment: How do you fill the variable Articles? Your code finds matching articles that are loaded. We can't help because you didn't include the part of the code where you load the data from the database. It is probably better to search for the articles directly in the database instead of the Articles object.